# Bitwise operation in C#

Tags: c#, byte, bit-manipulation

I'm a student working on a project for my college's chemistry department. Last year I wrote a C++ program to control a picomotor stage and have it communicate with a force pressure sensor, moving the stage up and down  until it touched the sensor. I used the DLL the company provided to write this program. It took me a while, but I got everything to work.

This year, I'm incorporating a second stage to the program and updating the entire program into a GUI using C#. The second stage and the force sensor only provide DLLs that work with C#, whereas the old stage was meant for C++. I was able to get all three to work in the new C# GUI program, it's all almost done save this problem:

In the old program, I was able to determine if the motors on the stage were moving via this function:

```
#define MOTOR_MOVING 0x01
byte isMoving = LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING;
```

byte LdcnGetStat(byte address) returns the last status byte of the module at the given address. According to the instructional manual I have, bit 0 is suppose to be set when the motor is moving. So, if I test it in my C++ program, using a bool variable, isMoving is 0 when the motors aren't moving, and 1 when they are, and it promptly returns to 0 after the motors stop moving. Works fine.

But in C#, I'm having problems incorporating this.

```
byte isMoving = LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING;
```

doesn't work, I have to do some explicit casting. So I changed it to this:

```
bool isMoving = Convert.ToBoolean(LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & 
Convert.ToBoolean(MOTOR_MOVING);
```

That doesn't give me an error, but LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) will always return "true" because it's never 0. If I just test the values that LdcnGetStat() spits out, when the motor is not moving, it returns 28, when it's moving, it return s 98. If I test again post-move, it returns 23.

Is there a proper way to deal with this in C#? I'm thinking of checking to see if LdcnGetStat returns the right numerical value, but that doesn't seem like the right way to handle it, especially since the values seem to change post-move.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Conditionals in C/C++ effectively compile down to comparisons against zero. So the expression `LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING` is equivalent to `(LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING) != 0`. In C# however, conditionals are done with actual `bool`s, so you can only use the second expression.

I can explain more if you need me to.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
bool isMoving = (LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING) != 0;
```

The expression:

```
byte isMoving = LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING;
```

Probably gives you an error about implicitly converting `int` to `byte`. You have to cast it:

```
byte isMoving = (byte)(LdcnGetStat(pico_addr) & MOTOR_MOVING);
```

In that case, `isMoving` will be equal to `0x01` when the motor is moving.

Comment: It really irks me that the `&` operator seems to assume the result type is the longer of its operands.  If *either* of the operands will fit in an unsigned type, there is no way the result can fail to fit within that type.  The `|` operator generally should assume the result type to be the longer of its operands, but perhaps with an exception if one of them is a negative constant (in which case the result is guaranteed to fit in any type that could hold that constant).

Comment: BTW, I also really wish that C# had a convenient operator or method defined on `int` and `enum` types which would test whether the "bitwise and" of two integer values was non-zero.  In C, I would say `if (myFlags & THIS_FLAG) do_something();`.  I don't think that having to write it as if ((myFlags & THIS_FLAG) != 0) do_something();` particularly improves legibility.

Comment: @supercat: Actually, the bitwise and even arithmetic operators on `byte` return `Int32`. For example, `byte b3 = b1 & b2;` will give an error even when `b1` and `b2` are declared as `byte`. `byte b3 = b1 + b2` will give the same error. On the other issue, I'm ambivalent. Probably because I did a lot of work in Pascal before C#.

Comment: Requiring a narrowing cast for `byte1 = byte2 and byte3` is obnoxious, IMHO.  I also really dislike the notion that `float` to `double` conversions are widening, but conversions the other way are not.  If anything, `double` to `float` conversions should be the widening ones, since casting an `int64` to `double` and then to `float` will either yield the `float` value which is closest to the original value, or one of two values that are essentially equally good.  It's possible that the cast to `float` may cause distinct values to become indistinguishable, but values which remain distinct...

Comment: ...will rank correctly with regard to `int64` values that were cast directly to `float`.  By contrast, converting `int64` values to `float` and then `double` only requires "widening" conversions, but most of the resulting `double` values will be wrong.  Further, given `double d=UInt64.MaxValue; float f=UInt64.MaxValue;`, which is larger, `f*f` or `Math.Pow(d,15)`? Each expressions will yield the best representation in its type for the correct mathematical value. Which is more correct--comparison as float, or as double?

Comment: `float`s have less precision bits than `double`s do - that's why `float` to `double` is a widening conversion